# How do I take the girls to the brothels?

Tags: bloodborne

After doing the first 25-50 hours of the game, I've spotted a lot of brothels that you can Talk to with red lights outside the door... but they don't say much, at the moment.

Anything from "who would let a stranger in at this time of night" to "oooh, ahhh"... lol.

I just came across a girl who pleads with you not to kill her, after being teleported by some strong enemy after death. I didn't kill her, thinking I could take her to the brothel instead... but I can't get her to come.

What do I do?

I remember reading somewhere that at some point girls ask for a safe place for refuge... so you take them to a brothel... :P

Comment: The only places I know of that you can take townspeople are the church at the Chapel Ward lamp and the clinic where you first start the game.

Comment: I'm totally sure that these places with the red lamps are not brothels. They seem to be homes of people.

Comment: SPOILERS!! The girl you are referring to requires you to be wearing a piece of "church" clothing to interact further. (Assuming she is a prostitute initially makes this a bit more amusing)

Comment: @5pike Talk to enough of them and you'll believe me... also, [red lights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Wallen)?

Comment: Just because there are red lights doesn't mean they are all brothels. But whatever.

Comment: One of them definitely is. But that's the only one. Most of them are just people.

Answer (score 9):

I can see how the 'red light' could be confusing, but the windows/doors with the red lamps are just homes of ostensibly sane citizens as far as I know.  Most of the people you meet just tell you to take a hike, but some give you items, small quests, or want you to tell them about somewhere safer to take refuge.

The 'safe place' you can send people is **Oeden Chapel**, which you can access after completing Central Yharnam, by defeating Father Gascoigne.  You'll need to talk to the beggar in the chapel before you can start sending people there.  Look for the red cloaked figure on the floor near the lantern.

There is a second place where you can send people - *Iosefkas clinic*. Iosefka can be found behind a set of double doors, at the top of the steps behind the '1st Floor Sickroom' lantern. She'll eventually ask you to send people to her.

*Notes*

*There is a time sensitive cutoff for saving these people, which is the defeat of Rom the Vacuous Spider. After that, returning to their locations will elicit "no response".*

*You actually can talk to a prostitute in one of the homes, although she says she's 'off during the nights'.  In fact, she is one of the people who is looking for a safe place.*

*I believe the lamps outside these homes are actually filled with incense that keeps the beasts at bay.  The beggar in the chapel explains that all of the incense there is what keeps the beasts from entering, and Arianna the whore mentions when you speak to her at her home that she is almost out of incense.  Just speculating though.*

Comment: There is a second place where you can send people - Iosefkas clinic. Iosefka can be found behind a set of double doors, at the top of the steps behind the "1st Floor Sickroom" lantern. She'll eventually ask you to send people to her.

Comment: Note that there is a time sensitive cutoff for saving these people, which is defeating Rom. After that, returning to their locations will elicit "no response".

Comment: @originaluser Thanks, I didn't know that.  Added to the post!